# Python selenium, undetected-chromedriver will not allow me to change my fingerprints

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am not able to change my browser fingerprints when using undetected-chromedriver, I tried to change my useragent and it did not work, is undetected-chromedriver blocking it from happening for some reason?

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options,version_main=118)

# Changing my useragent fingerprints
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

driver.get('https://amiunique.org/fingerprint')

time.sleep(40)
```

Comment: `options.add_argument("--user-agent=...")` You're missing the `--`

Comment: I tried it, same issue, it is not working

Comment: You need to add the option **before** you call `uc.Chrome()`.

Comment: it worked now thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

If you simply added this before defining the river, everything would have worked out perfectly. Instead, you put the Option after defining the driver.
The update code would then be:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options,version_main=118)    

driver.get('https://amiunique.org/fingerprint')

time.sleep(40)
```

Please let us know if that work or if you have a further question!